# Exporting OpenLayers/GeoServer Image without Canvas

Tags: canvas, openlayers, geoserver

My application is dynamically creating KML files that are overlayed on a map using OpenLayers and GeoServer. I would like to export this combination map/overlay as a single image.

Using Canvas as my renderer, I can accomplish this successfully with the "toDataURL()" function.

Unfortunately I need to support IE7/8 where Canvas is not available. The "Excanvas" javascript library also does not emulate this functionality.

What other alternatives do I have? I'm now resorting to reading in the background map into an image buffer and attempting to manually draw my KML vector data on top of it, then serving that up as a single image. Not only does this sound like re-inventing the wheel, but I'm fairly certain I'm not going to correctly convert the map coordinates (in lat/long) to screen coordinates (taking the projection into account) and my image will be skewed and not match what is displayed by OpenLayers/GeoServer.

Are there any Java libraries that can do the lat/long to screen coordinate conversion for me? I know what my output projection needs to be.